# "Open Case" page customization?

Tags: civicase

I did some significant customization of CiviCase over a year ago for an agency I work with. It was all through the front end with custom fields and the like, not any programming at the time.

They never got around to using it, but are now starting to. Formerly the custom field sets only showed up on the "Manage Case" page after case creation, and made sense in that context, now they are showing up on the "Open Case" page and everything is in a seemingly nonsensical order, pushing required fields like "Subject" way down the page. The former behaviour was a bare-bones "Open Case" page with no custom fields.

I can't find any way to customize the "Open Case" page either by re-ordering or removing elements. I'd settle for bringing the required Case fields of Subject, status, etc. to the top above my custom field sets. The "Order" field in the field set seems to have no effect on how things are displayed on the "Open Case" page.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? The only thing web searching has turned up for me is a conversation which led to the current sequencing and naming of the default elements.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For rearranging, you can use https://civicrm.org/extensions/rearrange-fields-new-case-form.

For hiding, you can insert some css `display: none` for the fields/rows. See https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/resources/#css-stylesheets

Comment: Excellent! Thank you.